# Solve variables given f(x)

Tags: calculus

I was given the following question:
[image]

How would I go about solving a and b?

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous at $x = 1$ implies that: $a = \dfrac{a}{1} = b - 2(1) = b - 2$, also:

$f'(1^{+}) = f'(1^{-})$ gives: $-a = -2$. Thus: $a = 2$, and $b = a + 2 = 2 + 2 = 4$

Comment: $f'(1^+) = f'(1^{-1} )$ gives $\frac{-a}{1^2} = -2\iff a = -2 \iff a = 2$. We don't square the coefficient

Comment: Yes, and the function needs to be continuous to be differentiable. That is why Dark-Chocolate is trying to find a and b such that the function is continuous.

Comment: @candido Yes, that is not what my comment is addressing. Read carefully please. I am simply correcting Dark's evaluation of $f'(1)$ from the right $f'(1) = -a,\;$ not $-a^2$.